# Installing tinyMCE with npm in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, tinymce

Im trying install TinyMCE in angular 6 (it needs to be this version) but I get error on implementing EditorModule in app.module

```
ERROR in node_modules/@tinymce/tinymce-angular/editor/editor.component.d.ts(8,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub page for the TinyMCE Angular wrapper makes this statement:

> **Support**
>
> *Version 4.0 is intended to support Angular 10. For Angular 8 and below we recommend using previous versions of the wrapper.*

...so I would bet you are trying to use the most recent version of the wrapper with a version of Angular that it does not support?